# Kafka Connect MirrorSourceConnector overwrites min.insync.replicas

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are using a Kafka Connect `MirrorSourceConnector` to mirror topics from cluster A to cluster B. Cluster A has a single broker, cluster B has three brokers.

On cluster B, we have the topics configured with `min.insync.replicas = 2`. The moment that the connector becomes active, this setting gets overwritten to 1 for the mirrored topics.

We can't figure out how to prevent this from happening. Since the connector's producer by has `acks=all` by default, we expect that it can cope with a topic with ISR 2, eventhough the source topic has ISR 1. Is this the wrong assumption?

Below is the config that we use

```
"connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
"name":"foo",
"topics":"foo_bar",
"sync.topic.acls.enabled":"false",
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
"replication.policy.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy",
"refresh.topics.interval.seconds":"30",
"refresh.groups.interval.seconds":"30",
"replication.factor":"3",
"source.cluster.alias":"ni",
"source.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"ni:9092",   
"target.cluster.bootstrap.servers":"nini1:9092,nini2:9092,infrackafkap03.nini3:9092",
"target.cluster.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-256",
"target.cluster.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
"target.cluster.sasl.jaas.config": "...";"
"producer.override.bootstrap.servers":"nini1:9092,nini2:9092,infrackafkap03.nini3:9092",
"producer.override.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-256",
"producer.override.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
"producer.override.sasl.jaas.config": "..."
```

We expect the ISR on cluster B to not be overwritten by the connector